# How to push results of a for loop into a new array MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

So I'm currently writing some script to calculate the time it takes to invert a full NxN matrix compared to a sparse matrix of the same size and then plot the times. I can do this easily using a simple vector like:

```
N=1000;

for i=1:10:N;
Afull=randi(9,i);
tic
inv(Afull);
tFull(i)=toc;
end

plot(tFull)
```

But when I try to use logspace everything breaks. Instead of only storing 10 results of the loop (which I chose in the logspace function) it also stores the other ~890 numbers as zeros which is really messing up my plots. I think my error is with the loop index.

```
N = round(logspace(2,3,10));

for i=N
Afull=randi(9,i);
tic
inv(Afull);
tFull(i)=toc;
end

plot(tFull)
```

My questions is this: Is there a way to fix my loop index or is there a way to simply push the result of each iteration into a new array. I can do this in JS easily, but MATLAB seems a little more difficult. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, it's quite straightforward in Matlab as well:

```
N = round(logspace(2,3,10));

for i=1:length(N);
Afull=randi(9,N(i));
tic
inv(Afull);
tFull(i)=toc;
end

plot(tFull)
```